# Pulling updates from Azure for an Orchard instance

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, orchardcms

I have setup Orchard CMS via Azure one click install. Pulled the code initially by running:

```
git remote add azure https://<username>@localgitdeployment.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/localgitdeployment.git
```

I then did a pull with (keeping it simple):

```
git pull azure master
```

So I have the repo locally, but with the CMS, I can add modules, etc... via the admin panel and that updates on Azure, but when I try to do a pull or fetch using same as above, it says I am up to date, but the new modules do not show up locally.

I have no branches setup as I am only using the 'master' branch.

So curious, where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks much.

Comment: No one has any input on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the files are changed in your Azure Web App, you need to commit these changes by executing ‘git commit’ command.  Then you could pull these changes to your local. Steps below are for your reference.

1. Open KUDU site of your Azure Web App.
2. Navigate to wwwroot folder.
3. Execute following command.

```
git add .
git commit -m addnewfiles
```

[image]